# Java SE 6: How to open files externally by Runtime.getRuntime().exec() on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, runtime, exec

I'm using Java SE 6 and want to open files in an external process by a predefined program. Currently I am using the following code for pdf files for example:

Windows:

```
public static Process openFile(File file) {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 10.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe \""+file.getAbsolutePath()+"\"");
}
```

Ubuntu Linux:

```
public static Process openFile(File file) {
    return Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/evince \""+file.getAbsolutePath()+"\"");
}
```

On windows this works just fine for all files. But on ubuntu, as soon as there's a space within the file path, it tries to open multiple files. Here's an example:

```
contract.pdf -> works on windows and ubuntu
contract 1 (copy).pdf -> works only on windows, ubuntu tries to open 3 different files (contract, 1, and (copy).pdf)
```

What special character do I need to tell ubuntu that it should handle file paths with spaces as one file ?

Thanks for your help in advance!
Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try using [Desktop.open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29)

> Launches the associated application to open the file.
>
> If the specified file is a directory, the file manager of the current platform is launched to open it.

Or you can try

```
return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ 
        "/usr/bin/evince", file.getAbsolutePath() });
```

Comment: Hi Peter. Many thanks for your fast answer! I can't use Desktop.open since I need the Process object to track the file state. But your second suggestion just works perfect!

Comment: The second option assumes you have broken up all the argument already. ;)

Comment: Yes, I assumed that :-) Thanks.